# Android Studio - Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Whenever I try to run my Android app using the emulator it gives me error saying **"Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"** along with **"Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer"**. Any solution?

Comment: Try `Genymotion` software instead of AVD. It is fast and light.

Comment: Found a solution for now but definitely gonna try Genymotion. Thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should Wipe data in avd manager and cool boot it . 
I hope it works coz it worked for me when i got the same error

Comment: then try making a new one with different rom

Comment: I found a solution, I disabled Intel VT in BIOS and enabled it again. Worked for me. Emulator now runs smooth. Thankyou for the help.