# Android-Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

`Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

**I also deleted the avd file in .android and reinstall the emulator but still same issue**

From answers is to increase the emulator's ram but in newest update i have no option to increase it

[image: new project]
similar posts but nothing help

[Android Studio - Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52908457/android-studio-emulator-process-finished-with-exit-code-1073741819-0xc00000)

[Many errors while opening the emulator. How to fix those errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086877/many-errors-while-opening-the-emulator-how-to-fix-those-errors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deleted the old emulator nexus-5x and install nexus 6 after that you can change the Emulated Performance    Graphics  from automatic to software it worked for me

[image]

[image]

so any emulator will work if you change to software as above

Answer (score 0):

You need to check:

Your size on disk is not full - this's often happen due to creation of some virtual devices that are unused

The RAM size of emulator is not minimum as your requirements

One more thing that I personally use: Use Pen Drive as a RAM

Comment: I used the recommended  2 GB ram, i updated studio also but still same issue