# My Android Studio emulator is not working correctly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jetbrains-ide

I downloaded the Pixel emulator and Android API 25, but when running it
appears for a few seconds and then disappears

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

In the Event Log, this is what appears

[image: image 3]

I need help pls

Comment: what's the expected behavior? are you running an app in the emulator, or only wanting to run and use the emulator? otherwise, looks like it's running in expected behavior to me.

Comment: I tried to use the emulator normally and also run an application, both gave the same result

Comment: Do you also have a LogCat output?

Comment: There is nothing in the LogCat, it only shows that it is disconnected

Comment: Have seen/tried: [Android-Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59031475/295004) Failing that, please [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68765474/edit) with PC specs (CPU/GPU/RAM/Hard drive space) and which OS (Win/Mac/Linux) you are using.

Comment: I just tried, the same thing happened, the emulator appears with the screen off for 4 seconds and then turns off

Comment: My pc specs

AMD FX 6300 ( six core processor )
8gb ram
GTX 1050
311gb/464

Comment: @FatimaBernardesH1N1 If your problem got solved then please accept as answer!

Answer (score 8):

The same Problem got me a few months ago:
I fixed it by doing this:

**Whenever you run the project or app you have to clear the data of that AVD**

**To wipe the data of Emulator follow these steps-**

> Go To AVD Manager then you will see all emulators there then simply wipe data. ie- like in this image shown.

*step 1*

[image]

*step 2*
[image]

*step 3*
[image]

Comment: @FatimaBernardesH1N1 If your problem got solved then please accept as answer!

Answer (score 0):

I also had random emulator crashes, everything would work for a short while, but then the emulator would just disappear as if it had stopped. The emulator.exe would still be running task manager, no way to recover the window and the `.lock` file couldn't be removed.

Even just starting the emulator and swiping the home screen left and right (not even starting my app), or going into the the apps drawer and back would cause the the emulator to stop working properly.

What worked for me was to always start Android Studio as "Run as administrator". So right click on the startmenu shortcut and select `Run as administrator`.

[image]

Not sure why it randomly stops working otherwise, I'm sure the Android Studio QA team thoroughly tests this on real-world laptops outside of Google labs right...? /s