# How to run avd in android studio without error?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed a new version of **android studio**
Whenever I created the virtual device AVD it shows
**The process for **Avd** has terminated** .
I used the older version but still facing the issue.I have tried various methods
from Youtube like **installing reinstalling haxm** and downloading imagesx86 but did not solve the problem
PLZ help me!

Comment: You need to attach more details if you want any help. What is the error exactly? It should be in Event Log or Run tabs

Comment: Your question is not complete. Give more information about your problem.

Comment: you can see this answer [why emulator is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68765474/my-android-studio-emulator-is-not-working-correctly/68768476#68768476)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to forget AVD of android studio and start using other AVDs like:
NOX or Genymotion which are faster and lighter.