# Emulator is not working in android studio latest version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have run my app but still **Device Manager** is saying

> No emulators are currently running. To launch an emulator use the **Device Manager** or run your
> app while targeting a virtual device

As you can see a green dot in the emulator that means "Emulator is running"

[image]

And some time emulator is showed but when I click on screen then emulator gone

> I think this version of the android studio has more bugs when compared to its previous version

Do you guys have any **tricks or solutions?**

Any help will be is **always appreciated!**

Comment: Is this a new AVD or created with an older version? Without console output of the emulator, that's alike "it's not working", which is not an error description. "Wipe data" (or simply creating a new AVD) might rather be the answer, instead of deleting lock files.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I am not able to wipe data

Comment: emulator not working is an understatement, for me it has rendered totally unusable my presses are not acknowledged and the emulator is totally unstable

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I have **2 Solutions** so you can try both if one doesn't work

#### Solution No 1

Select device manager and select your device and select the drop-down menu

[image]

---

then click on the show on disk option

[image]

then delete all files that have the `.lock` extension and run your emulator again.

[image]

## Solution No 2

You can get a normal emulator like previous time android studio have, so to get the previous emulator in the new version of android studio you can do these steps

open the settings tab by following the below steps or by pressing **Ctrl + Alt + S**

> Select **File** > **Settings** > **Tools** > **Emulator**

then **unTick** the option name **Launch in a Tool Window** then click okay
now you got the previous emulator. and if in the emulator you got any issues you can check [This Solution for Emulator on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68768476/15739040)

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem and deleting the .lock files does not work. Creating new AVD's doesn't solve the problem.. @Typo did you fix this?

Comment: @MennoSpijker now you can check the answer again!

Comment: Solution no 2 solved the issue.

Comment: @rojarand if you think it will help future's dev then please upvote  this answer 

Comment: Solution no 2 worked for me as well, thanks!!

Comment: It got reset to a tool window, but didn't have an Emulator tool window option to view - changing the setting fixed it for me -thanks

Comment: grazie. La soluzione 1 per me ha funzionato. Però ho eliminato file e cartelle con estensione ".lock".

Comment: Solution #2 apply to Giraffe on windows 10 works! :D

Comment: Can confirm solution #2 worked for me as well! Could you elaborate on why this works?

Answer (score 3):

In my case after I downloaded the second patch of bumblebee, my emulator was not working either. But after I did search for another update, << Help -> Check for updates >> android studio downloaded an update for emulators and now my emulators are working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think android emulator in android studio bumblebee does not simply work, because I have uninstalled the whole android and apply the aforesaid solutions but nothing work, I keep receiving "The emulator process for AVD Appl has terminated."

Better to install previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

Go to View -> Tool Windows -> Emulator. So you can see emulator.
I am on mac OS Big Sure. Android Studio Bumblebee.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a **Flutter** project, run from the terminal `flutter doctor`. When I did it, it reported that the SDK is not found, then I could set it for Flutter, and accept the licenses. It solved my device issues!