# How to run emulator outside android studio?

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

I am using Android Studio bumbleBee version in Windows 10 . Appears in a window when I run the emulator. My monitor is small and it is better to have it separately as before.

[image]

Comment: you can follow solution no 2 in this answer [Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70981809/15739040)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**There are three methods that I can think of.**

1. **Thanks to [@vishal beep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70981757/emulator-is-not-working-in-android-studio-bumblebee/70981809#70981809) answer**, You can simply go to `file` => `setting`=>search `emulator` in the search field=>select `emulator`=>uncheck `launch in a tool window`. Screenshot below.

[image]

2. **Since it is a flutter project Instead of going to `device manager` you can simply**

- Click on the `device list` first and
- Select `Refresh` if you don't see your emulator
- Once refreshed you should be able to see the emulator like the screenshot below.
- select the `emulator`, and run your application.

[image: here].

**3. Or you can run the emulator as usual and then right-click on the emulator window and choose `View mode`=>`Select Float option` instead of `Docked Pinned` screenshot attached below**

[image: here]

Thanks, Keep coding

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but do you know why? why Android studio introduced such a feature, it is very annoying.

Comment: @shady-mohamed-sherif  I don't know why it was developed this way, though
It always felt that this tool needs to be managed when it is floating.
Some people are used to it and don't have a problem with it and manage it, but for those who have a much, much bigger screen, this was a pleasant experience.

Answer (score 8):

Simply Go to **Preferences**.. >**Tools** > **Emulator** and then and then uncheck ***Launch into tool window***

For windows user Go to **Settings** >**Tools** > **Emulator** and then and then uncheck ***Launch into tool window***

**Note :** Before Doing this activity close all running Emulators and if needed restart the Android studio after changing the **Emulator** settings

[image: Android Studio Preferences]

Answer (score 5):

Go to setting -> tools ->emulator and unselecte launch in a tool windows

Comment: It should be noted that the simulator should be closed first, then the steps should be executed.

Answer (score 1):

A CLI way to open the emulator without opening android studio is to run the following from terminal:

1. `cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator` *Ensure your Android sdk path*
2. `./emulator -avd YOUR_EMULATOR_ID_HERE` For example mine was `Pixel_6a_API_33`

To find out which emulators you have you can use this command after doing step 1: `./emulator -list-avds`