# Emulator not working in Android Studio Dolphin

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I'm using AS 2021.3.1.17 on Windows 10.

My emulator is Pixel 3a with API 28 (Pie).

Whenever I try to run my code, it says "gradle build finished" and "launch succeeded" but the emulator page still says "No emulator are currently running."

I've tried:

- reinstalling AS
- updating the gradle plugin to 7.4
- wiping the emulator data
- cold boot
- deleting it and making a new one
- changing graphics from 'automatic' but it's disabled and unclickable

I've tried both solution on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70981757/emulator-is-not-working-in-android-studio-latest-version) and both doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the Android Studio emulator does not work.
It is better to use similar software like GenieMotion along with the emulator.
In general, my suggestion is to migrate from Windows to Linux, Linux does not have many problems and your emulator works most of the time.
But be sure to use other emulators and don't limit yourself to your Android Studio emulator